# Limiting node.js's memory usage

Tags: node.js, memory, ram

I am trying to limit a `node.js` application from using to much memory and I've found out about the `--max-stack-size` & `--max_executable_size` options that are available within V8 to pass when invoking the file, but how should I combine these and possible other arguments to limit max memory usage to 1GB?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

https://github.com/joyent/node/wiki/FAQ

> What is the memory limit on a node process?
>
> Currently, by default v8 has a memory limit of 512mb on 32-bit
>   systems, and 1gb on 64-bit systems. The limit can be raised by setting
>   --max_old_space_size to a maximum of ~1gb (32-bit) and ~1.7gb (64-bit), but it is recommended that you split your single process
>   into several workers if you are hitting memory limits.

Value is in megabytes, I believe.

Comment: The default limit increased to ~1.5GB around node 2.  See https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/3370#issuecomment-148108323

Answer (score 17):

It's now, `--max-old-space-size` no technology limits...

for example `node --max-old-space-size=8192 ./app`. We create limit in *8Gb*

Answer (score 3):

There are two ways to increase the maximum memory size of V8:

1. Using a [CLI option](https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#--max-old-space-sizesize-in-megabytes): `node --max-old-space-size=4096 memory.js`
2. Using an [env variable](https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#node_optionsoptions): `NODE_OPTIONS='--max-old-space-size=4096' node memory.js`

Here's a small script that shows you the memory usage of your application:

```js
const process = require('node:process');

const used = process.memoryUsage().heapUsed / 1024 / 1024;
console.log(`This app is currently using ${Math.floor(used)} MB of memory.`);
```